# selectively deactivate (power off) pcie slot?

Tags: hardware, intel-graphics, power-management, hybrid-graphics, pcie

the title basicly says what I'd like to do:

- my machine has integrated HD4000 graphics and a more powerful PCIe card
- HD4000 is enough for everyday use, PCIe should be used only for gaming with Windows
- through bios I can set the primary card
- I'd like to disable (switch off, suspend) the PCIe slot when in linux to conserve power and also to turn off the PCIe card's fan

Is this possible? - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Your Motherboard should have a Switch to ON/OFF the PCIE Slots on the motherboard. This should be used in conjunction with Lucid Virtu or some other software where your Monitor is connected to the onboard video output. Check out these links:-

http://www.xtremesystems.org/forums/showthread.php?277311-Disabling-PCI-E-slot-why-not

http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z87%20OC%20Formula/